# How do I access Azure Key Vault using user credentials?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to write a simple application to access Azure KeyVault using my own, domain joined credentials. I don't know if it's the credentials part or how I'm accessing KeyVault, but I keep getting an "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined" exception.
I am able to access KeyVault using Azure PowerShell cmdlets, but not using C#.

Here's the code I have:

```
class Program
{
    const string ClientId = "MY AAD CLIENT ID";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, KeyVault!");
        var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken));
        var secret = client.GetSecretAsync("vaultName", "secretName").Result; // Throws Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined
        Console.WriteLine(secret.Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var authResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, ClientId, new UserCredential());
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

What could be causing this? I've scoured the internet and haven't found any sample code showing how to access KeyVault this way.

Comment: I don't think it is possible for you to access a key vault using your application id. I have made it work using Azure PowerShell Client Id: `1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2`. Can you try by replacing your AAD Client Id with this one?

Comment: You might want to check out this article that details exactly the sort of thing you are trying to do: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2016/10/31/using-azure-keyvault-to-store-secrets/

Answer (score 12):

As @varun-puranik said, you need t specify the `vaultBaseUrl` rather than the vault name.

There is new nuget package that allow to connect to [Azure Keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/) without specifying the Azure Active Directory Client Id.
This approach works when you're using a [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

- [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication)

You also need to install the [Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/) nuget package.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;

...

var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
     new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(
    "https://{{my-vault-name}}.vault.azure.net/", "{{my-secret}}");
```

Answer (score 5):

The VaultName needs to be the URL to the KeyVault, not just the name of the Vault. 
For example, if the name of your KeyVault is TestKeyVault, then you need to use the following code -

```
var secret = client.GetSecretAsync("https://testkeyvault.vault.azure.net:443", "secretName").Result;
```

Rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: You dont need the 443 port in the url. Thats implicit cos its HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, try passing your secret's version as a 3rd parameter.

For example:

```
var secret = client.GetSecretAsync("vaultName", "secretName", "secretVersion").Result;
```

Comment: The .Result instead of using an await was EXACTLY what I needed (Using await doesn't seem to work).